# Null is not an object while trying to import from react-native-appearance in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I just updated expo to SDK 35 because I wanted to use the new react-native-appearance module to make the dark and light mode dependent of the systems settings. I followed the steps from the docs carefully. (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/appearance/) But if I try to import anything my iPhone 11 Pro Max Emulator gives me the following warning:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeAppearance.initialPreferences')

<unknown>
    polyfill.tsx:15:68
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    index.tsx:9:24
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    App.js:4
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
<unknown>
    AppEntry.js:4
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:331:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:197:45
global code
    <unknown file>:0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Haven't found anything online since this is a pretty new feature.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/expo/react-native-appearance/issues/11

Comment: I looked at this... but there isn’t any solution mentioned that is actually working... the only guess is to do exactly as the docs say... which is what I did and it’s still not working

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [link your module](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md).

On iOS that looks like this:

```
$ npx pod-install
$ react-native run-ios
```

Answer (score 0):

not supporting react-native-appearance in expo.
you can use colorscheme and appearance from react native

```
app.json configuration:
{
  "expo": {
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic"
  }
}
```

In EAS Build and custom development builds you'll need to install the native module expo-system-ui otherwise the userInterfaceStyle property will be ignored. Running expo config --type introspect will warn if the project is misconfigured:

```
» android: userInterfaceStyle: Install expo-system-ui in your project to enable this feature.
```

Bare projects

### iOS configuration

You can configure supported styles with the UIUserInterfaceStyle key in your app Info.plist. Use Automatic to support both light and dark modes.

### Android configuration

Appearance locking requires react-native@0.63.3 to work correctly.
Ensure that the uiMode flag is present on your MainActivity (and any other activities where this behavior is desired) in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
    ...
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode">
    Implement the onConfigurationChanged method in MainActivity.java (react-native@0.63.3 don't need this):

   

     import React from 'react';
        import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Appearance,useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
        import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'; 
        import { DefaultTheme, DarkTheme } from '@react-navigation/native';// automatically switches bar style based on theme!
        
        export default function App() {
          const colorScheme = useColorScheme();   or, const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();
    
    console.log(colorScheme)
        
          const themeTextStyle = colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightThemeText : styles.darkThemeText;
          const themeContainerStyle =
            colorScheme === 'light' ? styles.lightContainer : styles.darkContainer;
        
          return (
            <View style={[styles.container, themeContainerStyle]}>
              <Text style={[styles.text, themeTextStyle]}>Color scheme: {colorScheme}</Text>
              <StatusBar />
            </View>
          );
        }
        
        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          container: {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          },
          lightContainer: {
            backgroundColor: '#d0d0c0',
          },
          darkContainer: {
            backgroundColor: '#242c40',
          },
          lightThemeText: {
            color: '#242c40',
          },
          darkThemeText: {
            color: '#d0d0c0',
          },
          text:{
            color:'#fff',
            fontSize:22,
            fontWeight:"bold",
          },
        })
```